# Rotate marker in react-leaflet v4 - React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v4

I´m having trouble trying to rotate the marker in react-leaflet.

I have seen some examples where it is done with an older version of react-leaflet using leaflet-rotatedmarker. See below... have tried using both these examples without any result, have also tried to override css with `transform: rotate(18deg);`, but that did not work either. Any help will be appreciated

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
     ...
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.2",
    "leaflet-rotatedmarker": "^0.2.0",,
    "react-leaflet": "^4.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2"
  },
```

Result:

```
import 'leaflet-rotatedmarker';
import L, { LatLngBoundsLiteral, LatLngBounds, Icon, LatLng, map } from "leaflet";
...
let m = L.marker([51.505, -0.09]).addTo(map);
m.setRotationAngle(180);
```

[image: error1]
[image: error]

Working example with a older react-leaflet version:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/92wjp?file=/src/RotatedMarker.jsx:77-149)
[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652984/importing-module-that-extends-a-class)

Comment: Have you tried to install the types of rotatedmarker
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/leaflet-rotatedmarker

Comment: If that does not work and you only want to have custom icons, you can pass a icon directly to the react-leaflet <Marker> component. If you go this route you have to convert the icon to a divIcon, I have shared my code for doing that before e.g. here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346434/multiple-doughnut-chart-as-markers-over-openstreetmap/74349018?noredirect=1#comment131267992_74349018

Comment: Adding @types/leaflet-rotatedmarker worked, I didnt see @types/leaflet-rotatedmarker in the documentation. Do all packages have @types included for typescript?

Comment: It depends, packages can ship with their own typings. But if they do not you will hopefully be able to find them under the @types packages. 
Definitely Typed is more of a fallback, where anyone can help to provide types for packages. 
You could read up more on it here 
https://www.w3schools.com/typescript/typescript_definitely_typed.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add leaflet-rotatedmarker:
[npm source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-rotatedmarker)

If you are using typescript use:

```
yarn add @types/leaflet-rotatedmarker


import { MapContainer, Marker, TileLayer, Tooltip } from "react-leaflet";
import 'leaflet-rotatedmarker';
....
              //add rotationAngle
              <Marker
                icon={myIcon}
                key={data.key}
                position={[data.latitude, data.longitude]}
                rotationAngle={data.angle}
              >
              </Marker>
```